# Microsoft Botframework: How to use Telegram Parameters or sending NewLine?

Tags: botframework

I'm trying the new Botframework from Microsoft. When sending a message with `\n` there is no linebreak in the message. How can I solve that?

In the Telegram API there is an parameter called **parse_mode** (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) to activate HTML. Than I could use "<br />" for that, but I don't know how to set this parameter. Can someone help me by sending linebreak or Telegram-parameters?

Greeting
Max

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BotFramework uses Markdown.  To represent a paragraph break you need to have a blank line (i.e. "\n\n")

Markdown like this:

```
This is
paragraph one

This is 
paragraph two
```

Will be rendered as

```
This is paragraph one
This is paragraph two
```

See documentation at:  http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-content/#markdown-paragraphs

Comment: Seems does not work in newest versions, need to split messages by `'\n'` symbol on my own.