# New Line in Bot Framework for deploying on Telegram

Tags: c#, botframework

Method 1:

```
public async Task WelcomeAsync(
        IDialogContext context,
        IAwaitable<Message> argument)
{
    var message = await argument;
    message.SetBotConversationData("DateTime", DateTime.UtcNow);

    StorageAccess.StoreTemporaryLog(
    StorageAccess.GetDateTime(message.GetBotConversationData<DateTime>("DateTime")),
        "user",
        message.Text);

    await context.PostAsync(
        "Welcome to VAM Insurance Bot\n" +
        "Do you already have a policy or do you want to buy a new policy?\n" +
        "1.Already\n" +
        "2.New\n" +
        "Please enter the correct choice:");

    StorageAccess.StoreTemporaryLog(
        StorageAccess.GetDateTime(message.GetBotConversationData<DateTime>("DateTime")),
        "bot",
        "Welcome to VAM Insurance Bot\n" +
        "Do you already have a policy or do you want to buy a new policy?\n" +
        "1.Already\n" +
        "2.New\n" +
        "Please enter the correct choice:");

    context.Wait(AlreadyNewAsync);
}
```

Method 2:

```
public async Task AuthenicateClientAsync(
        IDialogContext context,
        IAwaitable<Message> argument)
{
    var message = await argument;
    StorageAccess.StoreStructuredLog(
        StorageAccess.GetDateTime(message.GetBotConversationData<DateTime>("DateTime")),
        message.GetBotUserData<string>("policyNo"),
        "user",
        message.Text);

    if (DBAccess.AuthenticateOTP(message.Text))
    {
        await context.PostAsync("You have been successfully authenticated!");

        StorageAccess.StoreStructuredLog(
            StorageAccess.GetDateTime(
                message.GetBotConversationData<DateTime>("DateTime")),
            message.GetBotUserData<string>("policyNo"),
            "bot",
            "You have been successfully authenticated!");

        await context.PostAsync(
            "What would you like to do?\n" +
            "1. View your policy\n" +
            "2. Renew you policy\n" +
            "3. File an insurance claim\n" +
            "Please enter the suitable options number:");

        StorageAccess.StoreStructuredLog(
            StorageAccess.GetDateTime(
                message.GetBotConversationData<DateTime>("DateTime")),
            message.GetBotUserData<string>("policyNo"),
            "bot",
            "What would you like to do?\n" +
            "1. View your policy\n" +
            "2. Renew you policy\n" +
            "3. File an insurance claim\n" +
            "Please enter the suitable options number:");

        context.Wait(ViewRenewFileClaimAsync);
    }
    else
    {
        await context.PostAsync(
            "The OTP that you have entered is either incorrect or expired.\n" +
            "Would you like to go over again?\n" +
            "Yes\n" +
            "No");

        StorageAccess.StoreStructuredLog(
             StorageAccess.GetDateTime(
                 message.GetBotConversationData<DateTime>("DateTime")),
             message.GetBotUserData<string>("policyNo"),
             "bot",
             "The OTP that you have entered is either incorrect or expired.\n" +
             "Would you like to go over again?\n" +
             "Yes\n" +
             "No");

         context.Wait(RepeatAsync);
    }
}
```

These are two methods of the dialogues in my project. I have deployed them on Azure and connected to Telegram. But the "\n" doesn't seem to be working everywhere. Its working in only some of the places, as you can see in the screenshot. As you can see, the dialogues of method 1 are not getting new lines. But in method 2, they are getting new line expect for the last one.
Visit https://storageangsu.blob.core.windows.net/policy-number-0123456789/image_damage for the image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BotFramework uses Markdown.  You can see the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448824/microsoft-botframework-how-to-use-telegram-parameters-or-sending-newline/36456756#36456756) or in the [BotFramework documentation](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-content/#markdown-paragraphs)

Comment: Thank you!! I had missed these resources.